# Stuck with a tricky existence proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Show that there exists a continuous function $f: [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such

$f(0) = 1$ and

$f(x) = \frac{2-x^2}{2} \cdot f(\frac{x^2}{2-x^2})$

$\forall x \in [-1, 1]$

I tried putting in $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ in the second condition to find that $f(1) = f(-1) = 0$. 
I also took the derivative of the second equation to find that:

$f'(x) = x (f'(\frac{x^2}{2-x^2})\frac{2}{2-x^2}-f(\frac{x^2}{2-x^2}))$

This gives me

$f'(0) = f'(1) = f'(-1) = 0$ but now I'm stuck. Anybody see a way?

Comment: Is not really clear to me what you want to do... What you mean by "show that there exists...". You have defined your function. Do you want to find an explicit form?

Comment: I believe you are incorrect umberto. the function is not yet defined.

Comment: You can show that $f(-x) = f(x)$. That doesn't solve it but simplify the problem a little bit. Plus we don't know if we can differentiate $f$... We only know it's continous.

Comment: @Rivten That might help. I'll try some more.

Comment: Also, I don't know if this might help but : if you study $$x\mapsto \frac{x^2}{2-x^2}$$ you can see that this is a bijection. And the inverse is $$y \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{2y}{y+1}}$$ So, inversing your equation, you have $$\forall y\in [0,1], \quad f(y) = (y+1) f\left(\sqrt{\frac{2y}{y+1}}\right)$$ Probably useless though...

Comment: @Rivten All information is useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's find the **most general** solution.

Let continuous function $f : [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ satisfy
$$
f(x) = \frac{2-x^2}{2} \cdot f\left(\frac{x^2}{2-x^2}\right)\qquad x \in [-1,1].
\tag{$1$}$$
and $f(1)=1$.  Observe $f$ is even.  Define $G : (0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
G(y) := \frac{1}{y}\cdot f\left(\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)
$$
Put $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ into $(1)$ to get
$$
y G(y) = yG\left(\frac{2y}{y^2+1}\right) .
\tag{$2$}$$
Now if $\phi(y) = 2y/(y^2+1)$, observe that the iterates $\phi^{[n]}(y)$ converge to $1$ as $n \to \infty$ for any $y \in (0,1]$.  From (2) we have
$$
G(y) = G(\phi(y)) = G(\phi^{[2]}(y)) = \dots,
$$
so that
$$
G(y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} G(\phi^{[n]}(y)) = G(1) = f(0) = 1
$$
for all $y \in (0,1]$.  Thus $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$, and thus for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: Would you care to explain $\phi$ further? is $\phi^n(y)$ the $n$-derivative to $\phi$?

Comment: $\phi^{[n]}(x)$ is the $n$th iterate:  $\phi(\phi(\phi(x))) = \phi^{[3]}(x)$.  That's why I put the word "iterate" there when I first mention it.

Answer (score 6):

I recall solving this problem before... was it on a Putnam? Sadly, I don't remember what leap of intuition led me to the answer.

One may take $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. It is clear that $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and that $f(0) = 1$, and one sees that

$$\frac{2-x^2}{2} \cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{x^4}{(2-x^2)^2}} = \frac{2-x^2}{2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{x^4-4x^2+4-x^4}{x^4-4x^2+4}} \\
= \frac{2-x^2}{2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{4-4x^2}{(2-x^2)^2}} = \sqrt{1-x^2},$$

so that $f(x) = \frac{2-x^2}{2} f(\frac{x^2}{2-x^2})$.